# How to create a select query that selects a repeating value in one of colums only once from multiple rows(example inside)

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access

This is for example what I have(This is the result of a select query from different tables by different conditions let's call it Select X) :

```
ID c2 c3 c4 

1  A  de ys

2  A  rq pm

3  B  rq qs
```

I want a query that will give  only one row with  a certain value in c2, for example:

```
ID c2 c3 c4 

1  A  de ys

3  B  rq qs
```

or

```
ID c2 c3 c4 

2  A  rq pm

3  B  rq qs
```

I know how to do that  using a data structure but it's more complicated, I wonder if there is a way to do that using a query?

Edit : This is what I tried and it gives error : " Syntax error in From clause "
( If it matters X = `SELECT  Responses.ID,Responses.PostID,Responses.Responding,Posts.ID,Posts.UserID,Users.ID,Users.Username FROM Responses,Posts,Users WHERE Responses.PostID =3 and Posts.ID = Responses.PostID AND Responses.Responding = Users.ID`)

```
    SELECT(Select X).*
FROM (Select X) as (Select X)
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, Users.ID
  FROM (Select X)
  GROUP BY Users.ID
) AS t2 ON (Select X).ID = t2.ID
```

EDIT : well I'll leave this open but at the end I chosen the data structure way not the query way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable as t1
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, c2
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY c2
) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

This will pick the row having the minimum `ID` value within a group of same `c2` values. You can use `MAX` aggregate function to get the second result set.

**Note:** I've made the assumption that `ID` is the PK of your table.

**Edit:**

You can use a derived table from you `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT X ...) as t1
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, c2
  FROM (SELECT X ...) AS t
  GROUP BY c2
) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I didn't understand the use of another table, I have a select query and I want to perform what I said on the product of the select query that already have terms from different tables.

Comment: @user3575645 You can use the select query to produce a derived table and use that in place of `mytable`.

Comment: So which tables does t1 and t2 represent ? Sorry for the stupid questions my knowledge in queries is very little, and thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3575645 You have to place your `select` query in place of `mytable`, i.e. use it twice, like `SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT ... query here ) AS t1 ...`

Comment: Ye I understood what to put in from but what t1 and t2 represents ? which 2 tables are they ?

Comment: @user3575645 They are table *aliases*, `t1` represents `mytable`, whereas `t2` represents a derived table being produced by aggregating `mytable` in order to obtain `MIN(ID)`.

Comment: So instead of t1 I should write "mytable" which is actually my select query ? so Select(Select X) From (Select X) as (Select X ) etc... ? And t2 should stay t2 even in my query ? it doesn't matter which name I give it ?

Comment: @user3575645 Yes, use your query to produce an inline table.

Comment: Hey I've edited the post to show what I tried and it gives me a syntax error in from clause, this is exactly my query as written only I replaced X with the actual value which is also given if needed.